# I need masked textbox in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex, textbox

- only numbers must be in that textbox
- that entries have to be in 100 between 500
- TextBox Needed to include 3 Decimal Places

I don't want any mistakes while values inserting to database.

Do I need to use jQuery or ASP.NET Validation Controls?

If jQuery is the useful one, then which plugin will I use? Or if it is asp.net RegEx Validator, which Validation Expression will I use?
Or is there any free ASP.NET Extended TextBox ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This jquery plugin works great, and it's very customizable.
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo

Remember, even if the control/plugin you use is very good and limits the user to what you want, you should still verify on the server side because users can bypass your controls with cross-site scripting

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [MaskedEditExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) from the AjaxControlToolkit.  It might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Ajax Toolkit and use the Masked Edit Extender, its very easy to use :-)
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_MaskedEdit.ashx