# Can you make a "separator" in ASP.net Textboxes? (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I was just curious if it's possible to put a "separator" (Not sure what you'd call it) in a textbox in ASP.net. For example, I want a textbox on my form to be a blank textbox with "blank:blank:blank" so they can just type the time, and another to be "blank/blank/blank" for the date, and so on. I've tried googling it for a bit but didn't find what I was looking for, probably because I'm calling it a seperator, and I'm not sure how accurate that is. I was hoping it could be done that way, but if there's another way, I'm using C#. Let me know if I explained that right at all or if you can recommend anything. As before, I appreciate the help from this community!

Comment: What you're looking for is called *masked input*.

Comment: Do a search for "masked input", is that what you're looking for?

Comment: You are looking for a "masked input" => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096100/i-need-masked-textbox-in-asp-net

Answer (score 4):

Probably should start with checking out if an input mask meets your needs.  The AJAX Control Toolkit might be a good place to start when looking at easy to use controls.  Check out their MaskedEdit control at: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/

Answer (score 2):

Use the MaskedEdit control in ASP.NET (from the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/)), should do exactly what you want.

[HOW TO Use the MaskedEdit Control in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Use%20the%20MaskedEdit%20Control.ashx)